# Voltage regulator current consmption

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter

Our pcb current consumption is less than `0.5mA` . We use a `3.7v lithium` battery, and the battery goes through voltage regulator `LD6806` that has a low dropout voltage ,and its output is the main 3v3 supply of the circuit .

The problem is , that we start to suspect that this regulator, is consuming more current than expected for some reason , and so our pcb now consumes more than expected.

This might be stupid assumption, but how can you check on the data sheet, whats the current consumption-the unwanted current- of this regulator, that is added to the original circuit current consumption ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1537429.pdf) look for "quiescent current" specifications.

You'll see on Table 10 (page 7) a series of figures for different conditions, and the largest listed is 250 uA (0.25 mA).

Also, graphs in Section 9.3, page 10.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the information from Brian be aware that many LDOs using a bipolar transistor pass element may take higher current when the input voltage drops to below the required output voltage.  The additional current is to provide the base drive for the pass transistor.

What is the part number of the regulator you are using?

You say you are using a 3.7V battery to provide 3.3V supply - that battery is only nominal 3.7V; as it discharges its voltage will drop and when fully discharged it will probably be ~2.8V, below your 3.3V supply rail requirement. Below about 3.4V the LDO will operate in dropout mode with the possibility of additional supply current requirements.

If you wish to extract the most battery life your circuit needs to operate down to ~2.7V.  Or you could use a 3.3V buck/boost switching regulator to keep supplying the 3.3v even when the battery is below that. There are many available these days as it is a common requirement.